# error with parenthesis on pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

using phpPgAdmin, I've tried to create a table in my database. But am getting an error after it has generated its code.

SQL error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" at character 91

CREATE TABLE "public"."main_products_common_dimensions" ("id" SERIAL, "product_id" integer(3) NOT NULL, "h_ft" character varying(15), "h_in" character varying(15), "w_ft" character varying(15), PRIMARY KEY ("id")) WITHOUT OIDS
```

What could be wrong with the parenthesis?

Comment: My advice - use PostgreSQL native PgAdmin or psql. They are way better for handling PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem - you cannot specify precision for `integer` type, so `integer(3)` is invalid type. Use `numeric(3)` or simple `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `integer(3)`: postgresql `integer` is always 4 bytes, signed.

Comment: Actually not even MySQL has an `int(3)` "data type". An `int(4)` in MySQL is the same thing as an `int` or an `int(16)`.